# Validating Xml using Xsd does not close the xml file after for use again

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I am having a problem closing an xml file so i can save it in another method.
For more insight I am adding a new node into an xml file. I then save the file. Then i use the validate to validate that the nodes added were correctly formatted according to the xsd file. If that is false i remove the previously added node. Then i try to save the file again and it fails saying it is still open.

If i change the validate method from being called and set the bool to false then it runs everything smoothly and removes the node and saves fine. I am trying to find out what i am missing on my validate method.

Here is the file that adds and calls the validation.

```
        doc.Element(doc.Root.Name).Add(root);
        doc.Save(fileName);

        bool b = ValidatingXml.ValidateXmlUsingXsd(fileNameXml, fileNameSchema);
        MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
        if (!b)
        {
            root.Remove();
            doc.Save(fileName);
        }
```

Here is the validation method i use.

```
    public static bool ValidateXmlUsingXsd(string xmlPath, string xsdPath)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(xsdPath));

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);
            MessageBox.Show("The xml document is formatted correctly.");
            settings.CloseInput = true;
            reader.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I don't see a big deal in being grateful to someone that takes the time to try to help.

Comment: I suggest you read the link I included with the comment.

Comment: There was never a defined rule disallowing hi or thanks as long as you don't go overboard.

Comment: And, did you read that link? It's pretty clear. If you want to thank someone, then accept their answer. If you _really_ want to be grateful, then don't waste the time of those who read your questions and try to answer them by adding various "chatter" that needs to be ignored. This is not a discussion forum. We are not meant to be having a pleasant conversation. You are meant to ask a clear question, and to get one or more clear answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because you are not cleaning up the `XmlReader`. Use

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings))
{
    // rest of code
}
```

You can do without the Close.

Answer (score 2):

The Close() method of your XML reader doesn't release the file handle. XmlReader implements the IDisposable interface so you should be creating/accessing your XmlReader via a `using` statement like this:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings))
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(reader);
    MessageBox.Show("The xml document is formatted correctly.");

    return true;
}
```

Once the using statement ends, the XmlReader will be automatically closed and disposed and that should resolve your issues with the file remaining open.

Comment: Thanks the answer was already given to me by the other answer but I will up this as it was useful and well explained.